# Single band antenna to dual band antenna

Tags: antenna, patch-antenna

I have designed a single band patch antenna with microstrip feed but my objective is to design a dual band antenna to resonate at frequencies 1.4 GHz and 2.45 GHz.

The current design is resonating at one of the two desired frequencies. How could I convert it into a dual band patch antenna?

The below image shows the designed patch antenna. How can I get the antenna to have a higher dB at its low points?

[image: The Designed Patch]

The image below shows the result for my patch antenna.

[image: Results for the designed patch antenna]

Comment: Might be easier to design a broad band patch centered at approximately 1.9 GHz and accept some performance roll off at 1.4 GHz and 2.45 GHz.

Comment: This *looks* like an academic problem; I can't quite follow your design: what is copper? What is substrate? Where is the feed? I'm not familiar with `S(P_in_T1, ...)`. If that is supposed to be S11, I would say you haven't really made an antenna at 2.45 GHz... You usually want input match to be better than 10 dB. I'd have to disagree with @SteveSh - a 55% bandwidth patch would be challenging in this scenario. There are many ways to achieve dual-band antennas - have you searched any papers or prior work?

Comment: @Jason S (P_in_T1, ....) means S11. The port name was P_in_T1 since it was driven terminal in my case. The green colored one is the copper or patch, the middle arm is the feed and the blue is substrate. It was supposed to have an 'E' like shape but somehow I ended up with this shape.

Comment: @calebsamuelD "somehow I ended up with this shape" Did you run an optimizer and it left you with this? That's not a good approach. I recommend starting with a candidate design that as an input match better than 10 dB and then work to shift that resonance.

Comment: @Jason I understand and I have (now) redesigned it and my input match is like -13.3 dB. However I still get only one of those two frequencies (1.4GHz or 2.4GHz). I can get both the frequencies separately by altering the dimensions but I still couldn't figure out how to make the patch resonate at both the desired frequencies.

Comment: @calebsamuelD is there a paper you're trying to replicate? What research have you done in dual-band antenna/patches?

Comment: @Jason not really. It was more like a self design (not preplanned) while I was just learning about miniaturized patch antennas and was curious how the dipole works even when the patches of monopole and dipole looks similar in few cases.